# Can an algorithm analyze the behaviour of a function and say if another function does exactly the same?

Tags: algorithm, nlp

**Can an algorithm analyze the behaviour of a function and say if another function does exactly the same?** For example, I have a function that clean input data but I need to know if another function does the same thing in another way, using different code.

**There exist such algorithm? Is this an [undecidable problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)?**

Comment: This question is better asked at http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is undecideable.

The reduction is simple, given an instance of [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems) `(f,x)` build a new function f' that does not stop for `x`. Produce `(f,f',x)` as input to the new algorithm.

Intuitively, if such a machine exists, you just solved halting problem because you'll be able to detect that `f` and `f'` have the same behavior, but you know that `f'` is in an infinite loop, so - so does `f`.

As a side note, if you are looking for an algorithm that checks ALL inputs, and not a single input - this is even harder, and this problem is not even in [RE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_%28complexity%29)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed undecidable.

It's at least as difficult as [the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

> Given the description of an arbitrary program and a finite input, decide whether the program finishes running or will run forever.

Part of determining whether 2 functions do the same for any given input would be to determine whether both actually halt for their respective inputs.